# How to run Spring XD on windows platform

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

What's the best practice for running Spring XD on a Windows platform?

Most of what I have seen has been just running it from the command line.  This is good for demos but doesn't work well in production environments.  Can a Windows Service be create to start and stop the Spring XD process?  Or what else can be used to manage the Spring XD run-time.

Really this could be applied to any embedded tomcat application.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tools out there for wrapping Java as a Windows service. That would be the way to go. We generally have not considered providing this level of support, even for linux platforms (i.e., providing daemon scripts). Furthermore, we do not perceive a lot of demand for running XD on Windows in production, so it's unlikely that we will provide this feature. However, if you believe there is significant demand in the community for running XD as a windows service, please submit a JIRA issue to https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD.